# Converting Character Array to Integer Array in C for ISBN Validation

Tags: c, arrays, string, integer, isbn

I really hope someone can give a well explained example. I've been searching everywhere but can't find a proper solution.

I am taking an introduction to C Programming class, and our last assignment is to write a program which validates a 10 digit ISBN with dashes... The ISBN is inputted as a string in a CHAR array. From there I need to separate each digit and convert them into an integer, so I can calculated the validity of the ISBN. On top of that, the dashes need to be ignored..

My thought process was to create an INT array and then use a loop to store each character into the array, and pass it through the atoi() function. I also tried using an IF statement to check each part of the CHAR array to see if it found a dash. If it did find one, it would skip to the next spot in the array. It looked something like this:

```
int num[12], i = 0, j = 0, count = 0;
char isbn[12];

    printf ("Enter an ISBN to validate: ");
    scanf ("%13[0-9Xx-]%*c", &isbn);

 do {
        if (isbn[i] == '-') {
            i++;
            j++;
        }
        else {
            num[i]= atoi(isbn[j]);
            i++;
            j++;
        }
        count++;
    } while (count != 10);
```

But that creates a segmentation fault, so I can't even tell if my IF statement has actually filtered the dashes....

If someone could try and solve this I'd really appreciate that. The Assignment was due Dec 4th, however I got an extension until Dec 7th, so I'm pressed for time.

Please write out the code in your explanation. I'm a visual learner, and need to see step by step.

There's obviously a lot more that needs to be coded, but I can't move ahead until I get over this obstacle.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So you just need to convert each digit of the string into an array of ints? Have you used `gdb` to find out where it crashes? And what should be done with `'X'` and `'x'`?

Comment: Since you're new to programming, another suggestion is to do what is known as "caveman debugging".  To do this, insert `printf`'s in your code to locate where the crash as occurring.  Not to be harsh, but one of the basic skills of programming is learning how to find your own errors.

Comment: it crashes when I use the `atoi` function. And it also needs to ignore the dashes, which I'm hoping my IF statement will achieve.

Comment: I did use `printf`'s to debug, but I did not include them... also the X's are to represent 10 if part of an ISBN.

Comment: I'll give you a hint, `atoi()` requires a string argument, but you're passing a single char.

Comment: Ok, but if I just pass it a string, then how do I separate each digit?

Comment: Also, as a point of code quality, your `i`, `j`, and `count` variables always have the same value.  Pick one to keep and use for all indexing and loop counting, and get rid of the rest of them.

Comment: You shouldn't have to pass a string; if it's a digit and not dash, or X, you can simply do `isbn[i] - '0'` to give you an int (well, char actually).

Comment: so you are saying to do it like this? `num[i]= atoi(isbn[i] - '0');`

Comment: Why would you do `atoi()` on a number type? :-)

Comment: `isbn[]` is `char`, so I'm converting to integer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your definition of `isbn` is not sufficient to hold 13 characters; it should therefore be 14 chars long (to also store the terminating `'\0'`).

Second, your loop is overly complicated; three loop variables that maintain the same value is redundant.

Third, the loop is not safe, because a string might be as short as one character, but your code happily loops 10 times.

Lastly, converting a char that holds the ascii value of a digit can be converted by simply subtracting `'0'` from it.

This is the code after above improvements have been made.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int num[14], i;
    char isbn[14], *p;

    printf("Enter an ISBN to validate: ");
    scanf("%13[0-9Xx-]%*c", &isbn);

    // p iterates over each character of isbn
    // *p evaluates the value of each character
    // the loop stops when the end-of-string is reached, i.e. '\0'
    for (p = isbn, i = 0; *p; ++p) {
        if (*p == '-' || *p == 'X' || *p == 'x') {
            continue;
        }
        // it's definitely a digit now
        num[i++] = *p - '0';
    }

    // post: i holds number of digits in num
    // post: num[x] is the digit value, for 0 <= x < i

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: for this assignment the ISBN is only supposed to have 10 digits, but I forgot about the terminating character.... I tried compiling your code, but it still doesn't display the values of `num[]` properly when i use `printf`

Comment: I included `printf("%d", num[i]);` within the loop, andthis is the result when I run it:
`Enter an ISBN to validate: 0-07-881809-5

91606417152327670000000`

Comment: @user1880970 Did you put that statement after it was assigned? Because, by then `i` is already incremented and thus you will get unexpected results.

Comment: @mdzura117 Which is wrong, because `i` would have the wrong value by then.